# Windows 7 streaming to

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, streaming

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate.
I am trying to use windows Media player to stream to my PS3.  They are both on the same router and I can stream using another program.
I go to media streaming options and try and select 'All Networks', because there I can see al my devices.  But as soon as I click ok to save the settings it closes the window and reverts back to 'Local Network' and here for some reason I cannot see any of my devices.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If they're both on the same router then they should both be in the Local Network. You may need to specifically allow the PS3 access under the [Media Streaming](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-settings-for-streaming-media-in-windows-media-player) options in the control panel.

You should see your PS3 listed in the following options page.

[image: Media Streaming Options]

If you can't see your PS3 in that list, you might need to scan for Media Servers on your PS3 first.

Comment: Have done all that.  The PS3 is online using the same router and I can stream using tversity.  But the only way to see all devices on my latop in media streaming options is to select 'all networks'. And when I click on it then on OK to set it it goes back to local network only.

Comment: Oh, that's probably just the default state for this window. If you `Show devices on: All Networks` then set your PS3 to Allowed, it should stay that way.